# Average payment delay - year to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I need to create a query that will allow me to determine the average payment delay per customer and I will hate to update that query each week.
Therefore I already calculated the delay with the date of the document and the date of the payment.

What I need to do know is to have a graph that will show the average of these delays per week but taking into account the previous weeks:

- Week 1: average of delays from week 1
- Week 2: average of delays from week 1 to week 2
- Week 3: average of delays from week 1 to week 3

and so on.

Today, we are week 11 so next week, I will need to have the result of week 12 automatically in my graph.

I already tried a graph using "Running Total in" in the settings of the pivot table 
but this result shows on:

[image]

Which is not helping because it's making a sum of the delays...

Here is how my code looks like:

```
SELECT ch.HDOCNO,
       ch.HDOCDATE,
       ch.HYEAR,
       week(ch.HDOCDATE)-1 as "Week",
       ch.HMDATE as "Payment date",
       AVG(ch.HMDATE-ch.HDOCDATE) as "Delay"
from AC_CHISTO ch 
where ch.HFYEAR = '2016'
  and ch.HMDATE IS NOT NULL
  and UPPER(ch.HDBK) = 'VEN'
GROUP BY ch.HDOCNO, ch.HDOCDATE, ch.HYEAR, ch.HMDATE
```

---

Here is an example of the data that I need to use:

[image: Data]

Comment: General GROUP BY tip, a selected column should either be argument to a set function (e.g. AVG), or be listed in the group by clause. (Seldom both.)

Comment: Not related to your question but, filtering with the upper() function generally slows down your queries.  Plus it's not necessary with sql server which is case insensitive.

Comment: @DanBracuk I think  the case insensitive will depend on the database Collation. If it's CS the upper may yield a different output.

Comment: @DanBracuk, sorry, to burst your bubble, but case sensitivity will depend greatly on the collation of your server and/or database.  If the OP is using a case sensitive collation and is unsure of the casing of the data or knows it will be mixed case, using UPPER is about the only way to ensure a correct match without doing some manipulation of the data in a temporary table.

Comment: Which version of sql-server?

Comment: Vincent, there are two methods you might try, neither of which can really be codified as an example without schemas and data.  First, look into creating and using a "Date" table that will allow you to very quickly create windows of dates in a set based manner.  Second, you might try utilizing a dynamic pivot based on date ranges.  There are a lot of examples on Stack, of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :)

I don't understand in which ways a "date" table will help, I only need to make an average of "subtractions" of dates and I dont get how a new table will help :/ do you have an example?
Thanks!

Comment: Does sql server support 'WEEK' as a function in your select statement? I'm using 2012 and 'Select week(getdate())' returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

The "date" table that Steve mentions is a fairly straightforward way to solve this problem. The basic premise is to use a pre-computed table to store all possible weeks, making it easy for you to aggregate your results over valid weeks. I've included comments in the code below to identify the different parts that I had to include just to return some example results using the data you provided.

```
--Create table to store source data (not part of a final solution, only needed in this case to return example data).
DECLARE @AC_CHISTO TABLE
(
    HDOCNO int,
    HDOCDATE datetime,
    HYEAR varchar(4),
    HMDATE datetime,
    HDBK varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO @AC_CHISTO
SELECT 610474, '02/26/2016', '2016', '03/02/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 611727, '03/04/2016', '2016', '03/11/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 611728, '03/04/2016', '2016', '03/09/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6133119, '03/11/2016', '2016', '03/15/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 613120, '03/11/2016', '2016', '03/15/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 601019, '01/07/2016', '2016', '01/29/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 603591, '01/21/2016', '2016', '02/29/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 600195, '01/04/2016', '2016', '01/21/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 600732, '01/06/2016', '2016', '01/21/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 601921, '01/13/2016', '2016', '01/28/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 602561, '01/18/2016', '2016', '01/28/2016', 'VEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT 603451, '01/21/2016', '2016', '02/11/2016', 'VEN'

--A table containing all weeks. In the final solution, this should be a real table prepopulated with 1 through 52, rather than a table variable.
DECLARE @AllWeeks TABLE
(
    [Week] int
)

INSERT INTO @AllWeeks
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15

--The actual solution begins here.
DECLARE @MaxWeek int

SELECT @MaxWeek = MAX(DATEPART(WK, ch.HDOCDATE)-1) FROM @AC_CHISTO ch

SELECT
    aw.[Week],
    AVG(results.[Delay]) AS AvgDelay
FROM @AllWeeks aw
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ch.HDOCNO,
           ch.HDOCDATE,
           ch.HYEAR,
           DATEPART(WK, ch.HDOCDATE)-1 as "Week",
           ch.HMDATE as "PaymentDate",
           DATEDIFF(DD, ch.HDOCDATE, ch.HMDATE) as "Delay"
    FROM @AC_CHISTO ch 
    WHERE ch.HYEAR = '2016'
      and ch.HMDATE IS NOT NULL
      and UPPER(ch.HDBK) = 'VEN'
) results
    ON aw.[Week] >= results.[Week]
WHERE aw.[Week] <= @MaxWeek
GROUP BY
    aw.[Week]
```